# Why am I getting "Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'items.split(',')')" here?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the following error while typing into the field filtered by 'completeList'.  Why is this happening?

**JavaScript**

---

```
angular.module('myApp', ['timer'])

    .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.gameOn = true;
        $scope.leaders = true;
        $scope.myScore = true;
}])

    .filter('completeList', function() {
      return function(items) {
        var list = [];
        if(items) {
          list = items.split(',');
          var last = list[list.length - 1];
          if(items.charAt(items.length - 1) != ',' || last.length === 0)
            list.pop();
        }
        return list;
      };
});
```

**HTML**

---

```
  <div ng-show="gameOn" ng-controller="LabelCtrl" class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h4>Enter comma-separated labels for this image</h4>
      <form role="form" class="form-inline" >
        <input ng-list ng-model="labels" placeholder="Enter labels" class="form-control" type="text" >
        <button class="form-control" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <h4>Labels</h4>
      <div>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="label in labels track by $index | completeList">
            {{ label }}
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: labels is not an array is it? it is the model from the input, so labels is a string. You need to do the split not as a filter, but before you repeat. ng-repeat="label in labels.split(',') track by $index". Or filter the list programmatically and put the filtered list into the scope for the repeat.

Comment: I think putting the filtered list into the scope is probably what I need but I don't know how to.  I'm an Angular newb

Comment: Ok, first I would change the filter function to be a regular function in the controller. Then add an event handling function for the form (ng-submit handler). In the event handler, that is where you would run your function to process the input's data, and then assign the output to some variable in the scope. Use that variable in the ng-repeat. Or, if not on submit, you could also use ng-change on the input.

Comment: An unrelated hint: You should remove `items.charAt(items.length - 1) == ','` or do you want the user always to enter a comma after the last label?

Comment: @aet It's a perfectly valid use case for a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that you only have a minor Angular syntax error. It is actually mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Filters should be applied to the expression, before specifying a
>   tracking expression.

...

> For example: 'item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id' is a pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction with a tracking expression.

Given this knowledge, just change your ngRepeat line to the following, it does work exactly as you intended and works perfectly on my side:

```
<li ng-repeat="label in labels | completeList track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the data structure of labels so here is my best stab at it.  Filters are applied onto the instance of your iteration of your loop.  It looks like you may be trying to apply the filter to the entire collection instead of that index of the loop.  The filter is applied to label not labels.  In this case you cannot split it.  Again I dont know your data structure so I am kind of guessing here.  It would be helpful if you could reveal what labels is.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: `labels` is shown in the HTML in the question.  It's the `ng-model` for an input field and will be a comma-separated list of words.  The objective is to create an ordered list item for each comma-separated term entered into the input field.  However, I only want completed words to be added to the list i.e. - words followed by a comma

Comment: Ok, the ng-repeat will not iterate over a string like that.  What you need to do is first apply some business logic: $scope.labels = myString.split(',');  This will give you an array that you can loop over.  Then follow Beyers advice above. I totally missed the first pipe in your ng-repeat.

Comment: @Breck421 you are wrong, ngRepeat will repeat over the output of the filter. So if the filter returns an array as per his example ngRepeat will function fine. I've tested his example given the changes in my answer and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Beyers his data set is "thing, thing2, thing3".  That is not a collection or a data structure.  It is a string.  Regardless of the filter I would respectfully disagree with doing that.  You are making your code difficult to understand.  As code authors, our primary goal is code that is readable and understandable by the next guy.  Thanks for the correction about the filters though.  Always learning something new.